# Looking for a cmd command in one line command to output url + filenames to text file

Tags: windows, cmd

for example i need to get all filenames in a folder to a file but i need an url appended before the names .
like https://example.something/filename.mp4

tried it with `dir > file.txt` but i cant append the url . help ?

Comment: Try the accepted answer at [https://superuser.com/questions/526029/append-to-start-of-filename](https://superuser.com/questions/526029/append-to-start-of-filename)

Comment: And for the percent encoded filenames, you could leverage powershell. Example: `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web; Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object { \"https://example.something/\" + [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode(\"$_\") }" 1> "file.txt"`